# how to dispose orphaned scopes in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular in my web forms application. I have an update panel where I navigate through user controls like a wizard. Each step/user control has its own controller. Since the element is removed while navigating through steps, A new scope is created each and every time the user control is loaded.

Now the issue is I can see all the orphaned scopes using ng-inspector. Is this a memory leak? How can I dispose the controllers which are no longer in use?

Thank you!

Comment: when the DOM elements are removed from a page, the `$destroy` event is called automatically.  Controllers are not destroyed unless the DOM element using `ng-controller=` is removed.  If you are using a routing system, like ui-router, this is normally handled in the `$routeChange` methods.

Comment: Even when the DOM element is removed. I still see the previously created scopes in the ng-inspector. When I change the models I see that it is affecting one or more scopes. for some reason I couldn't add the screenshot.

Comment: @SuneelKumarVanapalli, what version of Angular are you using? There was at least one memory leak with scopes that was just fixed [in 1.4.0-beta.6](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fb7db4a07bd1b0b67824d3808fe315419b272689)

Comment: I am using angular 1.3.x